# How to preseed a package's debconf values when installed as a dependency?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I want to install packages unattended and need to store the required debconf values before installation.

Is there a hook to run a command from the currently installing package that is executed before any dependencies are installed?

As an example take ldap authentication. I have created a package ldap-auth-config, that installs and configures pam to use ldap for authentication. Now, this package would have ldap-auth-client as a dependency which always fires up the debconf frontend to get a ton of questions answered.

For now, I help myself by having an ldap-auth-config-preseed package that needs to be intalled first and only pushes the required debconf values to make way for the real package to be installed unattended.

I would love to get rid of that extra package, but havent found any hint so far on how to get there.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I hope you figured this out in the 3 years since you asked it, but this has always worked for me.  I'm using an example here to autolaunch byobu...

```
sudo apt remove byobu     # for example purposes...

sudo apt install debconf-utils
debconf-set-selections <<< 'byobu byobu/launch-by-default boolean true'
sudo apt install byobu
```

Of course, this will work for whatever package.  You know this I'm sure, but run:

```
debconf-get-selections | less
```

to search for ones interesting to your package..

Comment: That is what my preseed package does, but you need to run in in an additional discrete step before installing the real package. I am still trying to get rid of that step - if I only could assure that the preseed package is installed before all others when installing the target package. Thus the question for a hook. So far I have not found anything. :)